# VMWare Server: Best way to backup images

Tags: backup, vmware, virtualization

What is the best way to backup VMWare Servers (1.0.x)? 
The virtual machines in question are our development environment, and run isololated from the main network (so you can't just copy data from virtual to real servers).

The image files are normally in use and locked when the server is running, so it is difficult to back these up with the machines running.

Currently: I manually pause the servers when I leave and have a scheduled task that runs at midnight to robocopy the images to a remote NAS.

Is there a better way to do this, ideally without having to remember to pause the virtual machines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VMWare server includes the command line tool "vmware-cmd", which can be used to perform virtually any operation that can be performed through the console.

In this case you would simply add a "vmware-cmd  susepend" to your script before starting your backup, and a "vmware-cmd  start" after the backup is completed.

We use vmware-server as part of our  build system to provide a known environment to run automated DB upgrades against, so we end up rolling back state as part of each build (driven by CruiseControl), and have found this interface to be rock solid.

```
Usage: /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <options> <vm-cfg-path> <vm-action> <arguments>
       /usr/bin/vmware-cmd -s <options> <server-action> <arguments>

  Options:
    Connection Options:
       -H <host>       specifies an alternative host (if set, -U and -P must also be set)
       -O <port>       specifies an alternative port
       -U <username>   specifies a user
       -P <password>   specifies a password
    General Options:
       -h More detailed help.
       -q Quiet. Minimal output
       -v Verbose.

  Server Operations:
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd -l 
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd -s register <config_file_path>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd -s unregister <config_file_path>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd -s getresource <variable>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd -s setresource <variable> <value>

  VM Operations:
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getconnectedusers
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getstate
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> start <powerop_mode>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> stop <powerop_mode>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> reset <powerop_mode>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> suspend <powerop_mode>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> setconfig <variable> <value>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getconfig <variable>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> setguestinfo <variable> <value>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getguestinfo <variable>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getid
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getpid
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getproductinfo <prodinfo>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> connectdevice <device_name>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> disconnectdevice <device_name>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getconfigfile
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getheartbeat
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getuptime
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getremoteconnections
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> gettoolslastactive
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getresource <variable>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> setresource <variable> <value>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> setrunasuser <username> <password>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getrunasuser
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> getcapabilities
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> addredo <disk_device_name>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> commit <disk_device_name> <level> <freeze> <wait>
    /usr/bin/vmware-cmd <cfg> answer
```

Answer (score 2):

Worth looking at rsync? If only part of a large image file is changing then rsync might be the fastest way to copy any changes.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy to follow guide for backing up VM's in vmware server 2 here: [Backup VMware Server 2](http://www.bdts.com.au/tips/46-vmware/57-backing-up-vmware-server-2-.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, VMWare Server has a scripting interface, available via Perl or COM. You might be able to use that to automatically pause the VMs before running the backup.

If your backup software was shadow-copy aware, that might work, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called (ahem) Hobocopy which will copy locked VM files.  I would recommend  taking a snapshot of the VM and then backing up the VMDK.  Then merge the snapshot after the copy is complete.